# Owl Carousel or alternative slider for Responsive GRID slider

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

[image]

WORK IN PROGRESS
http://jsfiddle.net/k0b4d4jL/

I need help regarding a slider set-up onther the form of a GRID, and it's very important to be responsive.

I'm using owl carousel at this moment (the image above is the psd mock-up) it should look as a grid and respond on browser size with the possibility of selecting a next grid of images when you push the next arrow.

```
$(".owl-demo").each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.owlCarousel({
    afterUpdate: function () {
      updateSize($this);
    },
    afterInit: function () {
      updateSize($this);
    }
  });
});

function updateSize($carousel) {
  var maxHeight = 0;

  $('.owl-item', $carousel).each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $image = $this.find('img');

    //Max height
    var prevHeight = $this.height();
    var thisHeight = $this.height('auto').height();
    $this.height(prevHeight);
    maxHeight = (maxHeight > thisHeight ? maxHeight : thisHeight);

    //Set image as background
    var imageSource = $image.attr('src');
    $this.css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imageSource + ')');
  });

  //Set equal height
  $('.owl-item', $carousel).height(maxHeight);

  $('#max-height').text(maxHeight + 'px');
}    




   <div id="demo">
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-demo">

        <div class="item">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
            <img src="http://www.debililly.com/wp-content/themes/Isabelle/images/4-3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="cell-img">

        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

The example above - kinda makes it responsive :(

Comment: Are you sure that you have all of the relevant CSS and JS that Owl Carousel supplies? Also your code you have each item with a class of item, should it not be owl-item?